# return no or yes if time difference is greater than 5min

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write following query but i find id defecult for me.

```
select id,comment,comment_date from comments;
```

Here I want to add a field, if current time is more that 5 minutes of comment_date
then it should show no else yes.

How to write query for above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One uses the [date_sub](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function for date delta, taking a time and an interval, as follows:

```
select id
     , comment
     , comment_date
     , case 
          when comment_date < date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute) 
             then 'yes' 
             else 'no' 
          end as answer
from comments;
```

Comment: Showing error: ` for the right syntax to use near ') then 'yes' else 'no' end as answer from comments  `

Comment: @user2302288 try now, there is no function date_diff, the one I wanted to use was date_sub...

Comment: Thanks for reply this code is working properly

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  id,
  comment_date,

  CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, comment_date, NOW()) > 5 THEN 'No' 
      ELSE 'Yes' 
  END AS isnew

FROM comments;
```